# How to loade module as a shorter name in Codeigniter (HMVC)

Tags: codeigniter, hmvc

How can I load a module in Codeigniter with a special short name? something like this:

```
$this->load->module('LongModuleName', 'ShortName');
```

So that I can access module with:

```
$this->ShortName...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to update the Thirdparty/MX/Loader.php

to look something like this:

```
/** Load a module controller **/
public function module($module, $params = NULL, $shortname=NULL)    {

    if (is_array($module)) return $this->modules($module);

if(isset($shortname))
  $name = $shortname;
  else
  $name = $module;

    $_alias = strtolower(basename($name));
    CI::$APP->$_alias = Modules::load(array($module => $params));
    return CI::$APP->$_alias;
}
```

Then to use it you would call:

```
$this->load->module('LongModuleName', NULL ,'Shortname');
```

The reason for the second parameter being null, is because this is looking for parameters